# Where can I learn mathematical style pseudo code?

Tags: algorithms

Some algorithms represented with the mathematical notations in some research papers, books, documentations. These expressions seem a little bit confusing.

For example :

```
for each edge (u, v) in GE do
    f(u, v) ← 0
    f(v, u) ← 0

    cf(p) ← min{cf(u, v) | (u, v) in p}
    for each edge (u, v) in p do
        f(u, v) ←  f(u, v) + cf(p)
        f(v, u) ← −f(u, v)

return f
```

Where should I learn these weird expressions? Any source (book, tutorial) or advice is appreciated. I have CS background but I can barely remember these things. I don't want to buy books like Discrete Mathematics because these books don't focus on the practical use and allows you to forget things $1$-$2$ days. Are there any books to teach me this expression with using programming?

Comment: I like to call this "Pseudo-algorithmic-language". Just read it as a plain sentence and read "$\leftarrow$" as $=$.

Comment: My impression is that people make up their own pseudo-code. There's no "standard" pseudo-code language --- that's what makes it **pseudo**code. I can only suggest that for a passage such as the one you pasted into your answer, read what the author of that passage says about the meaning of their own pseudocode.